# Why doesn't the while loop stop when the condition becomes False?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and was watching a 6 hr video by Mosh Hamedami.
He has shown an example of designing an elementary Car Game using a while loop.
The code is suggested is below:

```
command = ''
started = False
while command != 'quit':
    command = input('Enter a Command: ').lower()
    if command == 'start':
        if started:
            print("Car already Started! Let's go!")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car Started.... Ready to Go!!!")
    elif command == 'stop':
        if not started:
            print('Car already stopped!')
        else:
            started = False
            print('Car stopped!')
    elif command == 'help':
        print(" 'start' - to start the car\n'stop' - to stop the car\n'quit' - to quit/close the game.")

    elif command == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print('Sorry, I do not understand that!')
```

The above program runs perfectly,
But if we exclude the elif command == 'quit' block of code from the above program,
and give the
User-input: 'quit'
the program returns the Output: Sorry, I do not understand that!
But according to my understanding of the while loop, when:
User-input: 'quit'
The while loop should stop getting executed since while condition becomes False.

Now, if while loop stops executing with user-input "quit" then how the else block defined within the while condition is getting executed?

Comment: If you remove `elif command == "quit"`, then user input of `quit` is no different from user input of `foobar` or any other unrecognized command. Note that you aren't checking the condition again until *after* the `if` statement executed.

Comment: the while loop *does* stop executing, but only once the condition is evaluated again at the start of the next iteration

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how a `while` loop (or really any loop) works. The condition `command != "quit"` is only evaluated _once_ for every iteration. If the condition is `True`, the loop body is entered and run to completion. It does not exit immediately if the condition is falsified _during_ this execution -- it only exits the next time the condition is evaluated

Comment: You should probably just use `True` as the condition, and let the `if` statement explicitly terminate the loop when `quit` is entered.

Comment: ^ Or do `elif command != 'quit': print("Unrecognized")`, get rid of the `else`, and let the while loop handle the breaking

Comment: Use `break` in `else` block or use `while True` or get ride of `else` block totally>

Comment: Are there any better-quality, more popular versions of this question hanging around that other Python gold-badge holders know about? **Many** beginners have this problem and a canonical would be nice to have.

Answer (score 2):

A `while` loop does not terminate when the condition becomes false. It terminates when it *evaluates* the condition and the condition is found to be false. That evaluation doesn't happen until the beginning of each loop iteration, not immediately after some event occurs that will *allow* the condition to become false.

A better way to write this loop is to simply use `True` as the condition, as it doesn't require you to initialize `command` to a known non-terminating value, then let a `break` statement somewhere the loop terminate the command when appropriate.

```
started = False
while True:
    command = input('Enter a Command: ').lower()
    if command == 'quit':
        break

    if command == 'start':
        if started:
            print("Car already Started! Let's go!")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car Started.... Ready to Go!!!")
    elif command == 'stop':
        if not started:
            print('Car already stopped!')
        else:
            started = False
            print('Car stopped!')
    elif command == 'help':
        print(" 'start' - to start the car\n'stop' - to stop the car\n'quit' - to quit/close the game.")
    else:
        print('Sorry, I do not understand that!')
```

Of course, you don't need two separate `if` statements as I've shown here; you could combine them into one with `if command == 'start'` being the first `elif` clause of the combined `if` statement. But this provides an explicit boundary between "code that terminates the loop" and "code that allows the loop to continue".

Answer (score 1):

The program actually stops when you type `quit`, but before stopping it prints "Sorry, I do not understand that!". You can fix this by putting `command = input('Enter a Command: ').lower()` before `while` and in the end of the `while` like this  (so that `while` will check if `command != quit` immediately after inputing):

```
command = ''
started = False
command = input('Enter a Command: ').lower()
while command != 'quit':
    if command == 'start':
        if started:
            print("Car already Started! Let's go!")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car Started.... Ready to Go!!!")
    elif command == 'stop':
        if not started:
            print('Car already stopped!')
        else:
            started = False
            print('Car stopped!')
    elif command == 'help':
        print(" 'start' - to start the car\n'stop' - to stop the car\n'quit' - to quit/close the game.")
    else:
        print('Sorry, I do not understand that!')
    command = input('Enter a Command: ').lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement are executed sequentially.
The condition of the while statement is executed at the beginning of the loop while the "else:" is executed near the end. After the "input" is executed, the "else" near end of loop is executed first.